# I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel? Clarification Question

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, dual-nationality

An excellent [previous post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel) on this topic outlined the various different cases for how to travel on two passports.

One question relating to their Case 4: Different Names, Dual Citizenship Not OK.

(background note: this case involves traveller having Country A passport, and Country B passport, where Country A does not allow dual citizenship. Country C is a neutral third country where the traveller has the right to enter either visa free or with visa.)

When booking ticket A-C-A in Country A name, and C-B-C in Country B name, how do you manage to check into the C-B flight leg?

I.e. is it generally possible to book into the C-B flight leg without having to clear immigration in Country C, say at a transfer desk ?
Or could you do this checkin online, and carry a printed boarding pass that gets validated at the transfer desk ?

I plan to travel through Changi airport in the near future, and am not clear if it will be possible to check into this second leg without having to go through immigration.

Comment: Is C one of the countries that issued one of the passports? Or does C _care_ about one of the countries?

Comment: Michael, updated the question to highlight that C is a neutral third country. In my particular case it is Singapore, and doesnt 'care' about Country A not accepting dual citizenship.So when departing Country A, I would show only Country A passport, with visa for entering Country C.On arrival in Country C, instead of going through immigration, I am wanting to confirm that it is OK to go to the transfer desk and check in for the C-B leg using the Country B passport.

Answer (score 3):

It is *possible* that this can work, but you would need to depend on the checkin/gate agents of *both* airlines to be rather more flexible than they have to, in order to let you board the flights towards C.

Of course if one of your countries dislikes the other enough that it considers it a *crime* (treason?) to have a passport from the other one, then you can't even show the other passport at check-in without potentially getting into trouble, and then you have no way to convince that airline that the boarding pass you have is yours. So let's assume that's not the case.

The problem is then still that if the airline *away from* C refuses to let you board (for any reason, including a cancelled/overbooked flight, or simply because your *inbound* flight gets delayed en route), then the airline that brought you to C would be on the hook with C's authorities for bringing you there without having the right documentation to enter.

If you meet very sympathetic and service-minded agents at all places, it's not impossible that they'll look past this. But it is by no means certain -- so unless you're extremely risk-tolerant you would be advised to secure appropriate visas for country C with one (or both, as appropriate) of the passports.

Comment: Henning, sorry, I didnt not mention that when departing Country A for the Country C I would have a valid visa for Country C. So there should not be any issue in leaving Country A. The main concern/question was whether or not you can handle all of the check in for the C-B leg without having to go through immigration in Country C. I.e. on arrival in Country C, can I simply go to the transfer desk, and check in for the C-B leg using the different passport/name? thanks.

Comment: @rwm: So your question is simply whether you need to allocate time to go through immigration and security again while you change planes? That's very specific to how things are done at the particular airport you're transiting at -- and you probably need to ask again with that _specific_ question rather than obfuscating it with ABC variables. But on the other hand I don't see that different names and passports should matter for that -- if there is a transfer desk and you can get to it without immigration, just present whatever documentation you want to use for the second leg there.

Comment: (Of course, for all this to work you need to travel with cabin luggage only -- but you hopefully know that).

Comment: Henning, yes, with hindsight the question I am really asking is: Can I check in to a second flight at a transfer desk inside Changi Airport, using a different passport (dual nationality, different names) than what I arrived on. I can see now that the Country A/B/C info clutters the question, and is not directly relevant. Thanks for your answer.